# Удалить пробелы в телефоне JQuery

Tags: jquery

Имеется:

```
<a href="tel:+7 (800) 333-75-95" class="tel" id="tel">+7 (800) 333-75-95</a>
```

Как удалить пробелы внутри самого тега, понятно:

```
$('#tel').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace(/\s/g, '')); 
});
```

Но как удалить пробелы внутри **href="tel:+7 (800) 333-75-95"**, вот это понять не могу...

Comment: `var href = $(this).attr("href"); $(this).attr("href", href.replace(/\s/g, ''));` A `each` - не нужен. Выборка по `id` возвращает максимум один элемент.

Comment: @igor спасибо! Но, как обычно, чуть позже, понял, что нужно заменить не только пробелы, а любые другие символы, кроме цифр и "+". Заменить все символы - /[^-0-9]/gim . А как обозначить "+", не подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> удалить любые другие символы, кроме цифр и "+"

```js
var text = "tel:+7 (800) 333-75-95";
console.log(text.replace(/[^+0-9]/gim, ''));
```

*Update*

> необходимо удалить все символы, кроме цифр, плюса и "tel:"

Я бы предложил приставлять спереди "tel:" явным образом:

```
$('.tel').each(function() { 
  var href = $(this).attr("href"); 
  $(this).attr("href", "tel:" + href.replace(/[^+0-9]/gim, '')); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо снова, но снова я сделал упущение... таким образом удаляется и tel: делая ссылку не "звонящей". Получается, необходимо удалить все символы, кроме цифр, плюса и "tel:".

Comment: @Amsterdam я бы предложил приставлять спереди "tel:" явным образом: `$(this).attr("href", "tel:" + href.replace(/[^+0-9]/gim, ''));`

Comment: потрясающе, огромная вам благодарность! Задача выполнена идеально. Теперь все работает как нужно. Итоговый вариант взял такой (с обращением по классу, т.к. элемент на странице будет как правило не в еденичном экземпляре:

`$('.tel').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $(this).attr("href", "tel:" + href.replace(/[^+0-9]/gim, ''));
});`

Comment: @Amsterdam С выборкой по классу, конечно, `each` уместен.

Comment: если не затруднит, вы бы могли разместить этот вариант в качестве ответа, в новом сообщении, или отредактировав свое сообщение выше, а я бы отметил его соответствующим образом